# Landscape manager Client queued for days

Tags: landscape

I updated a computer (running Ubuntu 18.04.04) from that computer (i.e. logged in physically at the pc), had to do a

> $ dpkg --configure -a

in order to do

> $ apt-get update && upgrade

now from [Landscape](https://landscape.canonical.com/static/doc/user-guide/) gui this PC still shows as having package upgrades available.

If I tell Landscape server (Ubuntu 16.04.6) to perform the updates the activity shows as Queued endlessly. I have cancelled the activities after multiple days of being Queued. Additionally I can't get *any* scripts to run on that pc from landscape manager. They all show as Queued until cancelled.

Did I mess something up? How to get the upgrades to register in Landscape, and to get these commands to push through.

Should I not be doing upgrades from the PCs themselves anymore? That seems silly.

The Landscape Server is running Ubuntu 16.04.6

w/ 18.03 Landscape version

The Computer w/the issue is running Ubuntu 18.04.04

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and install the latest supported version as per https://docs.ubuntu.com/landscape/en/onprem please and see if the issues exist?

LDS 18.03 expired on 2019-Jun

Thanks